# Guarantee that a class can only be used by the thread that instantiated it

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I've created a class that is not thread-safe and can lead to bad bugs if assumed to be thread-safe.  While I work to make my class thread-safe, I'd like to make instances only usable by one thread.  Currently my implementation is to check that the current thread is the same as the thread used to construct the instance at every exposure point.

```
public class NotThreadSafeClass
{
    private readonly int _creatorThreadId;

    public NotThreadSafeClass()
    {
        _creatorThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    }

    public string ExposedProp
    {
        get
        {
            AssertSameThread();
        return "My Prop";
        }
    }

    public void ExposedMethod()
    {
        AssertSameThread();
        /* Do stuff */
    }

    private void AssertSameThread()
    {
        Throw.If(_creatorThreadId != Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                 @"NotThreadSafeClass is not thread safe.  Please don't use
           the same instance of NotThreadSafeClass in multiple threads.");
    }
}
```

*Note: Throw.If is defined in http://www.codeducky.org/10-utilities-c-developers-should-know-part-one/*

This pattern seems to work, but it's cumbersome and susceptible to bugs if a developer forgets to add this check to any new exposures.  Is there a safer and/or more elegant way to ensure that an instance is only used by one thread?

Comment: Just curiously... Why is it important that only the thread that created the class can use it?

Comment: Do you mean something like [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Your non-generic rewrite of `Throw.If` is harmful, because it leaves you with a non-descript exception.  It's also not the right level for reuse.  Put the ThreadId check and throw (of a properly descriptive exception) together into a helper function, then at least the burden of doing the check will be lower, and therefore less likely skipped.

Comment: @BenVoigt, good callout.  I actually am using a helper function which uses `Throw.If` to throw a more specific exception message.  I just excluded that helper function to simplify my example. I'll modify my example.

Comment: @BryanCrosby I'm writing a component that will interact with NUnit.  I simply don't trust that the interactions between my class and NUnit are working correctly because my unit tests display unexpected behavior when I try to use the component in different threads.

Comment: luc morin answer is the best option you can even try with [RealProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy(v=vs.100).aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

I think that short of using an AOP framework, you will have to "intercept" all such access to your class' methods/properties in your own code, just like you're describing.

I'm thinking [Ninject's Interception Extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.interception), or [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/aop.net)

Nothing is built into the language/framework for this.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Moved `ThreadLocal<T>` to a private field inside the class declaration.

Unless I completely misunderstand, `ThreadLocal<T>` should meet your needs. An example:

```
class Foo {
  private ThreadLocal<int> _internalState;

  public Foo() {
    _internalState = new ThreadLocal<int>();
  }

  public int IntValue {
    get { return _internalState.Value; }
    set { _internalState.Value = value; }
  }

  public override string ToString() {
    return _internalState.ToString();
  }
}

class Program {
  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    Demonstrate();
  }

  static void Demonstrate() {
    var local = new Foo {IntValue = 5};
    Console.WriteLine("Start thread value: {0}", local.IntValue);

    new Thread(() => {
      local.IntValue += 5;
      Console.WriteLine("New thread value: {0}", local.IntValue);
    }).Start();

    local.IntValue += 10;
    Console.WriteLine("Start thread value: {0}", local.IntValue);
  }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Start thread value: 5
Start thread value: 15
New thread value: 5
```

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's not.

Comment: This is great and I think get's me 90% of the way!  I'd want to throw an exception every time we try to instantiate the class the first time.  That functionality should be pretty easy to implement with use of a closed over boolean.  I'll have to do some refactoring to implement this, but I think it should work for me.  Thanks!

Comment: @StevenWexler `ThreadLocal` isn't sealed so you might be able to modify it's behavior to do what you need - not sure through